# color for span text

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML5 doc-type. I have created a span tag and given the text color as red but it is not applying anything to span when I run the page. But the miracle is it is working in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r9bP8/2/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>

body{margin:0; padding:0; }
.wrapper{width:1024px; height:768px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; background:url(../images/.jpg) repeat top left}
header{
    display:block; padding:0 125px;
    background-color: #007DC4; text-align:center;
    overflow:auto
}
header a:first-child{float:left; padding:15px 0}
header a:last-child{float:right; padding:15px 0}
.logo{ padding-top:8px ; display:inline-block }

.container{width:801px; height:700px; background-color:#FFF; margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px  #e1e1e1,  -2px 0 2px #e1e1e1;   
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0 2px #e1e1e1,  -2px 0 2px #e1e1e1;   
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px #e1e1e1,  -2px 0 2px #e1e1e1; 
}
.home_menu{
    width:500px; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto; position:relative
}
.test{ padding:35px 50px; width:150px; display:inline-block; float:left}
.test a{
    width:150px;
    float:left;  line-height:150px; 
    background-color:#0091ce ;
    border-radius:6px;  text-align:center;  vertical-align:middle;
}​
.test span{
    color:#F66
}​
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<header>
<a href="#"><fhj</a>
<a href="#" class="logo">fh</a>
<a href="#">gj</a>
</header>

<div class="container">
<div class="home_menu">
<div class="test">
<a href="#"><img src="images/channels.jpg" width="59" height="60" alt="channels" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a><span>test</span></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="images/.jpg" width="64" height="73" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a><span>uspan</span></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="images/.jpg" width="99" height="78" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a><span>htu</span></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="images/.jpg" width="76" height="49" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a><span>ggg</span></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="images/.jpg" width="71" height="68" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a><span>tehhhst</span></div>
<div class="test"><a href="#"><img src="images/.jpg" width="70" height="68" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a><span>bgfg</span></div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is it not working while running the page?

Comment: span text is taking red color only in fiddle but not in my html page. Try adding the code in html page and ru then its not taking the red color

Comment: Can you post the CSS? There might a different rule taking priority over the ones you posted on jsfiddle. Firebug add-on for Firefox is a handy tool to work out which rules are in effect.

Comment: @Ren I have edited the css. Copy the entire code in one html page then you can see that span is not taking the color given in css. But when you move the span class to the top of the css line it works but other css gets disturbed

Comment: When I copy the CSS, there are question marks after some of the final braces. When I remove these, it works for me locally. I made a few other changes also. I will post them as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments, I removed two question marks that had appeared on the `test a` and `test span` closing braces when I copied it. (Possible character encoding issue?)

I also added in omitted semi-colons and a type for the stylesheet.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body{margin:0; padding:0;}
  .wrapper{width:1024px; height:768px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; background:url(../images/.jpg) repeat top left;}
  header{
      display:block; padding:0 125px;
      background-color: #007DC4; text-align:center;
      overflow:auto;
  }
  header a:first-child{float:left; padding:15px 0;}
  header a:last-child{float:right; padding:15px 0;}
  .logo{ padding-top:8px ; display:inline-block; }

  .container{width:801px; height:700px; background-color:#FFF; margin:0 auto;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px  #e1e1e1,  -2px 0 2px #e1e1e1;   
      -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0 2px #e1e1e1,  -2px 0 2px #e1e1e1;   
      box-shadow: 2px 0 2px #e1e1e1,  -2px 0 2px #e1e1e1; 
  }
  .home_menu{
      width:500px; margin:0 auto; overflow:auto; position:relative;
  }
  .test{ padding:35px 50px; width:150px; display:inline-block; float:left;}
  .test a{
      width:150px;
      float:left;  line-height:150px; 
      background-color:#0091ce;
      border-radius:6px;  text-align:center;  vertical-align:middle;
  }
  .test span{
      color:#F66;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: BUt I am not able to see the question mark in my code. Where exactly is that?

Comment: I copied it into Scintilla text editor and it appeared here `.test a{
      width:150px;
      float:left;  line-height:150px; 
      background-color:#0091ce;
      border-radius:6px;  text-align:center;  vertical-align:middle;
  }?
` and here `.test span{
      color:#F66;
  }?
`. (See closing brace of each rule). If you copy this CSS over, it should resolve your issue.

Comment: yup tat solved but my doubt is how it is getting generated?? I am using Dreamweaver

Comment: Yes there are 2 question marks which need to be removed, which editor are you using, open your HTML in notepad and you may see it.

Comment: Well, I just copied and pasted the CSS you posted into notepad also. While it does not show the question mark, you have to push the arrow key more than once to navigate over where the invisible question mark is. Not sure what is causing it to be honest. It is not necessarily a question mark though - Scintilla will show it as that if it can't find the symbol referenced. You might want to post a new question as I can imagine that would be annoying. Is this question solved then?

Comment: @Ren yes thanks. But in this 4 year I have never faced this issue. still not getting tat how it is generating

Comment: Might have been copy and pasting code snippets off the net that had different character encodings?

Comment: Nope , This entire code is written from the scratch , not copied from any source

Answer (score -1):

it's default get NOW you set own **[EDIT](http://jsfiddle.net/r9bP8/3/)**

**Styling Links**

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

**Text Decoration**

```
a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: I know this. But my question is different, its about some css rule overriding

Comment: css rule not overriding, this is default browser rule apply [check this](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)

Comment: The default style sheet used to render HTML.

Comment: My question is about span tag. a tag is working fine in my page